# Mjpg_streamer can view web interface but not stream

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, webcam, mjpeg

My issue is that I am trying to configure mjpg_streamer to stream my webcam onto a web page with either my built in webcam or over a USB webcam. Using Mjpg_streamer, I am able to get to the page where it is supposed to display the stream "localhost:8080" and "localhost:8080/action?=stream" but I cannot see any image or get any errors printed out. Below you can see that my USB webcam does work with other programs besides mjpg_streamer.

[Webcam works with cheese but not with mjpg_streamer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MINIh.png)

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:7b0e Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 174f:14e6 Syntek 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc. MK260 Wireless Combo
Receiver
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 05a3:8830 ARC International <-This is the USB Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have checked numerous other sources but none of their fixes seemed to work for me. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=100818 This source seemed to be promising, but the fix was with the kernel version of their pi, but I'm currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Here is the command I use to start the stream (had to hand the path to input_uvc.so and output_http because those were giving me errors previously).

```
~/mjpg-streamer-code-182/mjpg-streamer-experimental$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/XXXXXXXX/mjpg-streamer-code-182/mjpg-streamer-experimental/plugins/input_uvc:/home/aquabotix/mjpg-streamer-code-182/mjpg-streamer-experimental/plugins/output_http mjpg_streamer -i "input_uvc.so -f 30 -d /dev/video1" -o "output_http.so -p 8080 -w ./www"
```

One more thing I would like to add is that a lot of people with a similar issue were able to see their stream using VLC and inputting the stream URL, but unfortunately this does not work for me either.

I apologize if this is long-winded and disorganized but I could not find any relevant answers to this question anywhere else.

Edit:Here is the output of executing the mjpg-streamer script I use, it contains the same command from above except has a line to kill any mjpg-streamer process that might be running before executing the command.

```
$ ./mjpg_streamer.sh 
mjpg_streamer: no process found
MJPG Streamer Version: svn rev: 
DBG(input_uvc.c, input_init(), 136): argv[0]=UVC webcam grabber
DBG(input_uvc.c, input_init(), 136): argv[1]=-n
DBG(input_uvc.c, input_init(), 136): argv[2]=-f
DBG(input_uvc.c, input_init(), 136): argv[3]=30
DBG(input_uvc.c, input_init(), 136): argv[4]=-d
DBG(input_uvc.c, input_init(), 136): argv[5]=/dev/video1
DBG(input_uvc.c, input_init(), 253): case 14,15
DBG(input_uvc.c, input_init(), 223): case 6,7
DBG(input_uvc.c, input_init(), 194): case 2,3
DBG(input_uvc.c, input_init(), 302): input id: 0
i: Using V4L2 device.: /dev/video1
i: Desired Resolution: 640 x 480
i: Frames Per Second.: 30
i: Format............: JPEG
i: TV-Norm...........: DEFAULT
DBG(input_uvc.c, input_init(), 355): vdIn pn: 0
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 96): Input name: Camera 1
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 109): Current size: 640x480
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 138): Supported format: Motion-JPEG
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 170):    Supported size with the 
current format: 1600x1200
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 170):    Supported size with the current format: 3264x2448
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 170):    Supported size with the current format: 2592x1944
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 170):    Supported size with the current format: 2048x1536
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 170):    Supported size with the current format: 1280x960
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 170):    Supported size with the current format: 1024x768
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 170):    Supported size with the current format: 800x600
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 170):    Supported size with the current format: 640x480
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 170):    Supported size with the current format: 320x240
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 170):    Supported size with the current format: 1600x1200
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 178): current resolution: 7
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 138): Supported format: YUYV 4:2:2
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 172):    Supported size: 1600x1200
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 172):    Supported size: 3264x2448
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 172):    Supported size: 2592x1944
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 172):    Supported size: 2048x1536
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 172):    Supported size: 1280x960
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 172):    Supported size: 1024x768
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 172):    Supported size: 800x600
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 172):    Supported size: 640x480
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 172):    Supported size: 320x240
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 172):    Supported size: 1600x1200
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, init_videoIn(), 178): current resolution: -1
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, enumerateControls(), 988): V4L2 API's V4L2_CTRL_FLAG_NEXT_CTRL is supported
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 873): V4L2 parameter found: Brightness value 0 Class: USER 
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 873): V4L2 parameter found: Contrast value 0 Class: USER 
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 873): V4L2 parameter found: Saturation value 0 Class: USER 
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 873): V4L2 parameter found: Hue value 0 Class: USER 
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 873): V4L2 parameter found: White Balance Temperature, Auto value 0 Class: USER 
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 873): V4L2 parameter found: Gamma value 0 Class: USER 
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 873): V4L2 parameter found: Gain value 0 Class: USER 
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 856): Menu item 0: Disabled
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 856): Menu item 1: 50 Hz
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 856): Menu item 2: 60 Hz
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 873): V4L2 parameter found: Power Line Frequency value 0 Class: USER 
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 873): V4L2 parameter found: White Balance Temperature value 0 Class: USER 
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 873): V4L2 parameter found: Sharpness value 0 Class: USER 
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 873): V4L2 parameter found: Backlight Compensation value 0 Class: USER 
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 858): Unable to get menu item for Exposure, Auto, index=0
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 856): Menu item 1: Manual Mode
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 858): Unable to get menu item for Exposure, Auto, index=2
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 856): Menu item 3: Aperture Priority Mode
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 881): V4L2 parameter found: Exposure, Auto value 0 Class: EXTENDED 
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 881): V4L2 parameter found: Exposure (Absolute) value 0 Class: EXTENDED 
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, control_readed(), 881): V4L2 parameter found: Exposure, Auto Priority value 0 Class: EXTENDED 
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, enumerateControls(), 1023): JPEG compression details:
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, enumerateControls(), 1024): Quality: 0
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, enumerateControls(), 1025): APPn: 0
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, enumerateControls(), 1026): APP length: 0
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, enumerateControls(), 1027): APP data: 
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, enumerateControls(), 1028): COM length: 0
DBG(v4l2uvc.c, enumerateControls(), 1029): COM data: 
o: www-folder-path...: ./www/
o: HTTP TCP port.....: 8080
o: username:password.: disabled
o: commands..........: enabled
DBG(input_uvc.c, input_run(), 400): launching camera thread #00
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL should be:

```
/?action=stream
```

not

```
/action?=stream
```